# QMC server Issue:Not allow to open any tab of QVS@servername

Tags: qlikview

I have a problem with QMC server.It is showing below error while trying to open the folder under: System > Setup > Management Servers > Qlikview Servers > QVS@nameserver.

> Error:
>
> Failed to retrieve settings from QlikView Server.
> Make sure that the QVS is available with the correct credentials.

The Qlikview services are running under different account (Administarator account) and the QMC server in which i'm trying to access QVS and getting error is under different account (my account). But both the accounts are under QV administrator group.

Is it mandatory to access QMC with the same account which we are using to run Qlikview services?

Currently, Qlikview services are running with administrator account. So can i change it to run under my account? will it cause any error in future if i change the account for the services which are running?

Comment: It is best practice to use the same account. there is no logic NOT using the same account - you only open yourself to more trouble

Comment: okay,thanx EldadT. But can we publish the QV report on QMC with different account also(QV services are running with different account)?Because right now,when i try to open the tab,i always got above mentioned error.So is it any other different issue over there?

Comment: Short answer is yes. you really should get some training, I feel a lot of confusion in your questions (non-qlik-logic on how things work and difference between qmc and qv "reports" (model) security)

Answer (score 0):

Please go to services and be sure that all services are running. In service properties you can set which account is running service:

[image: service properies]
QMC is console not server so it shouldn't matter.

When you go to Qlikview Servers in QMC, don't go to your server but check list of servers there. QMC which is handled by "Qlikview Managment Service" is communicating with Qlikview Server Service" on port 4747. So on your server list you should have qvp://SERVER_NAME you can check with telnet connection to SERVER_NAME on 4747

Comment: So can we use any account(Account which is added into QV Administrator) to run qlikview services? Also on QMC,i can see the list of servers there but the error which i have mentioned is not resolved.

Comment: QV Administrators and Administrators